# Datatables: dropdown in a cell

Tags: javascript, symfony, datatables

i'm trying to generate a table with Datatables.

I receive a json from my controller, here a sample:

[image]

this json can change (number of columns, name of the columns) and I can build my table with the good number of column and the good name.

My question is:

How can i do to have a dropdown when the "liste" have an array and a simple input when it's null?

Is it even possible?

EDIT :
I forget to explain something. The Json that I receive is a json to build the table not to fill it. So is it possible to do a columnsDef before the datas are in the cell.

EDIT n°2:
I used the solution that I accepted, but the problem was with my json. I tried to send a json to build and a json to fill the table. So I change my json and I send the list of options in the json to fill the table.

Hope it will help other people.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding the note "json to build the table not to fill it", yes, you can build a `columnsDef` dynamically.  See the bottom of my updated answer. But I suspect it still does not get you all the way to your solution. Maybe it will give you some ideas, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

1) With a drop-down.

2) With a formatted array (as an alternative).

### 1) With a Dropdown

The end result looks like this:

[image: with dropdown]

The datatables definition is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var dataSet = { "records" : [
    { "data" : "123456789",
      "liste" : null,
      "name" : "Nombre Enfants"
    },
    { "data" : "5678901234",
      "liste" : [ "Oui", "Non" ],
      "name" : "Transport"
    }]};

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet.records,
        columnDefs: [
          { targets: [ 0 ], 
            title: "Data", 
            data: "data" },
          { targets: [ 1 ], 
            title: "Liste", 
            data: function ( row ) {
              if (row.liste == null) {
                return null;
              } else {
                return buildDropdown(row.liste);
              }
            } },
          { targets: [ 2 ], 
            title: "Name", 
            data: "name" }
        ]
    } );

  function buildDropdown(data) {
    var dropdown = "<select>";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var option = "<option value=\"" + data[i] + "\">" + data[i] + "</option>";
      dropdown = dropdown + option;
    }
    dropdown = dropdown + "</select>";
    return dropdown;
  }

  } );
</script>
```

It builds a drop-down based on the assumption that a non-null value is an array. This may not always be the case in your data - just an assumption on my part.

### 2) With a formatted array

Just in case this is also of interest, DataTables has a built-in syntax for formatting array data, so it is displayed in a cell like this:

[image: formatted array]

In this case, you no longer need the drop-down builder function. Everything else is the same as option (1) except for this part:

```
{ targets: [ 1 ], 
  title: "Liste", 
  data: "liste[, ]" },
```

Specifically, the `[, ]` notation lets you format the array data.

I mention this only because it lets you display all the array data in the cell, rather than neeeding to click a drop-down. But that is just a suggestion.

You may find that other functions such as searching and sorting are better with this option.

### Update

The question has clarified that the table needs to be built dynamically from the data provided in the JSON.

You can pass variables to the datatables initializer - for example:

```
var col1 = { targets: [ 0 ], title: "Data", data: "data" };
var col2 = { targets: [ 1 ], title: "Liste", data: "liste" };
var col2 = { targets: [ 2 ], title: "Name", data: "name" };
var dynamicCols = [ col1, col2, col3 ];
```

The above `col1` variable defines the title for the column, and where the column will get its data (from the `dataSet.data` fields).

The `dynamicCols` variable can then be used in a `columnDefs` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet.records,
    columnDefs: dynamicCols
} );
```

However, I am not aware of a way to include a function in a columndef, using this approach (for example to present a cell's data as a drop-down, if needed).

There are additional techniques which can be used to make a datatable even more dynamic - several examples are available online - for example [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42893/dynamically-generating-columns). Without seeing a more detailed example of the JSON being provided, I am not sure if there are any additional suggestions I can make.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my problem is that i can't know the target because sometimes a column have input but sometimes the same target is a column with an array. So I can't do that.

Comment: @C.Ramp - OK - in that case, you can use my approach for every column, not one. If that is still not helpful then I guess I don't understand the situation - sorry about that. Perhaps you can provide more JSON samples in your question, to clarify?